# TikZ decorations.pathreplacing and lineto curve ignored

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

Why the decoration option is ignored ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{alamain/.style={%
    decoration={%
    lineto code={
        \draw[red] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) 
            to [out=10 , in=190]
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast) ;
        }
    },
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);

\draw [alamain] (0,0) -- (3,1) ;
\draw [blue] (0,0) to [out=10 , in=190] (3,1) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the decoration name `show path construction` and the action `decorate` that makes the decoration active. Finally, the second path overdraws so it is invisible you need to move it a bit to see

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{alamain/.style={%
    decoration={show path construction,%
    lineto code={
        \draw[red] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) 
            to [out=10 , in=190]
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast) ;
        }
    },decorate
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);

\draw [alamain] (0,0) -- (3,1) ;
\draw [blue] (0,0) to [out=20 , in=200] (3,1) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]